# ¿Porque cuando envió mi data de ajax y lo recibe mi jsp me marca como null?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Me gustaría saber como puedo pasar mi variable de javascript hacia mi archivo de JSP para a través de ahí mandarla al resto de mi aplicacion.

Codigo de JS:

```
function obtenerUrl() {
    var url;
    url = window.location.href;


    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.jsp', //This is the current doc
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'text', // add json datatype to get json
        data: ({url: "Hola mundo"}),
        success: function (data) {
            alert(url); --- esta alerta si la ejecuta y me trae lo que quiero
        }
    });


}
```

Codigo de JSP:

```
<% 
   String state = request.getParameter("url");
%>
```

Código de verificación:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var url="<%out.print(state);%>";
    alert(url);

</script>
```

Mi resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes colgar el código html completo?

Comment: Cual es el contenido de index.jsp? Que esperabas recibir al hacerle una solicitud post?

Answer (score 0):

Me suena algo raro cuando dices:

`alert(url); --- esta alerta si la ejecuta y me trae lo que quiero`

Ya que no haces un alert de `data` (lo que devuelve el server), si no de una variable ya declarada en javascript `url`.

Un ejemplo de lo que digo sería este

```js
var url = 'algo';
var promise = new Promise((rs,_rj) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    rs('myUrl')
  }, 2000)
});


promise.then((data) => {
  alert(url); // imprimes url pero no data
});
```

Revisalo por si es eso.